# Привязка TextBox к переменной

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

Есть переменная `string getTxt{get{....}}`  которая парсит текст.
Необходимо чтобы при вводе в 1-ом TextBox текст сразу парсился и выводился результат во 2-ой TextBox. Как мне это сделать? Это можно сделать через привязку?

[image]

Исходный код:

```
public partial class Editor : Window
{
        public Editor()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private string _getTxt;
        public string getTxt
        {
            get 
            {
            var md = new Markdown();
            md.ExtraMode = true;
            md.SafeMode = false;
            _page = md.Transform(code);
            return _getTxt;
            }
            set
            {
                _getTxt= value;
            }
        }
}

##################################
XAML

<Grid>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="222*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="281*" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<TextBox Grid.Row="0"/>
<TextBox Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/gc0PhbcJ
Вот исходник для примера. Мне нужно чтобы при изменении в 1-ом TextBox парсился текст и результат заносился во 2-ой TextBox

Answer (score 3):

Напишите обработчик события для TextBox1 - OnTextChanged.

В хэндлере:

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)  
{  
    //парсите TextBox1.Text
    TextBox2.Text = распарсенный_текст  
}
```

Comment: это будет уже совсем не привязка

Answer (score 2):

Не, так не пойдёт. Свойства не для того, чтобы проводить в них вызов парсера. Иначе не жалуйтесь, что программа будет виснуть.

Во-первых, разделите программу на Model, ViewModel и View. Вашей моделью является парсер, VM — переменные, где будет храниться текст, и View — ваш Editor.

1) View. Это очень просто:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Markdown}"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Parsed}"/>
</Grid>
```

2) Model. Тут всё тоже просто:

```
static class MarkdownTransformer
{
    public string Transform(string src)
    {
        var md = new Markdown() { ExtraMode = true,  SafeMode = false };
        var page = md.Transform(code);
        return GetTextFromPage(page);
    }
}
```

3) VM. Тут посложнее. Вам нужно заимплементировать DependencyProperty, как описано [тут](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750428.aspx).

```
class VM : DependencyObject
{
    // dependency property string Markdown
    // dependency property string Parsed
    // на изменение Markdown навешиваете OnMarkdownChanged
    async void OnMarkdownChanged(...)
    {
        if (isRunning)
            return;
        isRunning = true;
        string markdown = null, nextMarkdown = this.Markdown;
        do
        {
            markdown = nextMarkdown;
            Task<string> parse = Task.Run(
                   () => MarkdownTransformer.Transform(markdown));
            string parsed = await parse;
            this.Parsed = parsed;
            nextMarkdown = this.Markdown;
        } while (markdown != nextMarkdown)
        isRunning = false;
    }
    bool isRunning = false;
}
```

Вот вроде и всё.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно написать Converter (подробнее в Гугл) и указать его для привязки во втором текстовом боксе.
Т.е. в первом текстбоксе привязка к getTxt, а во втором привязка к первому, но через конвертер.
Если не разберетесь, могу объяснить подробнее.

Вот так, если через привязки (UI не виснет):

```
    //MainWindow.xaml.сs
    namespace WpfApplication1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Логика взаимодействия для MainWindow.xaml
        /// </summary>
        public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            private string _url = @"http://google.com/";
            public string Url 
            {
                get 
                { 
                    GetData(_url); 
                    return _url; 
                }
                set 
                { 
                    _url = value;
                }
            }

            private string _result = "";
            public string Result
            {
                get { return _result; }
                set
                {
                    _result = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Result");
                }
            }

            async void GetData(string _value)
            {
                if (_value != "")
                {
                    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
                    try
                    {
                        await Task.Delay(3000);
                        Result = await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(_value);
                    }
                    catch(WebException)
                    {
                        Result = "Не могу получить данные!";
                    }
                }
            }

            public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                this.DataContext = this;
            }

            #region INotifyPropertyChanged
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
            {
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
                }
            }
            #endregion

        }
    }
```

XAML (MainWindow.xaml):

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1" x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" DataContext="{Binding}" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:MyConverter x:Key="MyConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="0" x:Name="txt1" Text="{Binding Url}"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Result, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Вызов парсера в UI-потоке = зависание. Дискасс.

Comment: Возможно вы знаете о двусторонней привязке, нет?

Comment: Знаю. Ещё раз: в каком потоке выполняется код конвертера? Ответ: в UI-потоке. Видите?

Comment: Никто не мешает в конвертере выполнять код в другом потоке, а возвращать результат уже после парсинга. И если нужно сделать парсинг именно через привязки, то только так. (И, кстати, в WPF можно делать привязку асинхронной, что не вызывает зависание UI)

Comment: @Breaker: Не выйдет. Вам всё равно придётся заблокировать выполнение в UI-потоке до конца вычисления результата, иначе что вы отдадите в `return`?

---
А вот с асинхронными привязками _может_ сработать. Попробуете? (Просто поставьте в конвертере `Thread.Sleep(5000)` и посмотрите, не зависает ли UI).

---
Мне кажется, требование сделать конвертацию через привязки бессмысленно. В ТЗ может быть лишь _что_ мы хотим сделать, но ни в коем случае не _как_.

Comment: Через конвертер не прокатило, подвисал UI, сделал по-другому. Обновил ответ.

Comment: @Breaker: О, это уже лучше. Я бы всё же (1) убрал отладочный `Task.Delay`, (2) запускал асинхронное выполнение не на getter'е, а на setter'е, (3) Пытался бы оборвать запущенный Task, если url поменялся (CancellationToken), (4) предотвратил бы race между возможными несколькими запущенными `Task`'ами (что будет, если вторая загрузка обгонит первую?).